# Add two Fields from json File into one list, turn both into floats one of the Fields into a negative one

Tags: python, json, list

Python Code:

```
def konto_all():
    lst = [[], []]
    for index, x in enumerate(bankstm):
        kontoall = x["FIELD7"].replace(",", "."), x["FIELD8"].replace(",", ".")
        if kontoall != "" and index > 1:
            lst[0].append(kontoall)
            lst[1].append(x["FIELD1"].replace("-", ""))
    return(lst)
    
kontoall1 = konto_all()
kontoall = kontoall1[0]
print(kontoall)
```

Json File:

```
  {
    "FIELD1": "2020-05-27",
    "FIELD7": "",
    "FIELD8": "56.00"
  },
  {
    "FIELD1": "2020-05-25",
    "FIELD7": "109.00",
    "FIELD8": ""
  },
  {
    "FIELD1": "2020-05-20",
    "FIELD7": "78.90",
    "FIELD8": ""
  },
  {
    "FIELD1": "2020-05-19",
    "FIELD7": "56.90",
    "FIELD8": ""
  },
  {
    "FIELD1": "2020-05-19",
    "FIELD7": "46.80",
    "FIELD8": ""
  },
  {
    "FIELD1": "2020-05-18",
    "FIELD7": "",
    "FIELD8": "400.00"
  },
```

Current output:

[('', '56.00'), ('109.00', ''), ('78.90', ''), ('56.90', ''), ('46.80', ''), ('', '400.00')]

Wanted Output:

[56.00, -109, -78.90, -56.90, -46.80, 400.00]

Every String from FIELD7 should be a negative float.
Every String from FIELD8 should be a positive float.

Comment: You can use list comprehension, ``[float(d['FIELD7']) * -1 if d.get('FIELD7') else float(d['FIELD8']) for d in data]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
kontoall = x["FIELD7"].replace(",", ".") , x["FIELD8"].replace(",", ".")
```

is actually creating a tuple, which results in `[(val, ""), ("", val2), ...]`.

change that line to following and it will work as expected:

```py
kontoall = float(x["FIELD7"].replace(",", ".")) or -float(x["FIELD8"].replace(",", "."))
```

Here we set `kontoall` value to be field7 value if field7 has value else negative of field8, and cast it to float.